# What APP_PLATFORM used by default when compiled through Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

Ok, very simple Anroid.MK

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)    
include $(CLEAR_VARS)     
LOCAL_MODULE    := helloworld     
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../hello.c     
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

What APP_PLATFORM used by default ? 
This my platforms in NDK folders:

```
android-12\
android-13\
android-14\
android-15\
android-16\
android-17\
android-18\
android-19\
android-21\
android-3\
android-4\
android-5\
android-8\
android-9\
```

So ?

Comment: You might see if `ndk-build V=1` (on a clean project) results in printing compiler command lines in which you can see an include path referencing one of them.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can use anything up to the value of `minSdkVersion`. So if you used `minSdkVersion=9`, you should not use anything higher than 9.

Technically, it could build with a higher version, but you'll get (legitimately) a warning that you're using a higher version than you `minSdkVersion`.